# Can MVP be implemented in Android with Activities and Fragments as Presenters and Custom Views?

Tags: android, architectural-patterns, mvp, android-development

Lately my team has started considering the implementation of MVP pattern in some of our applications.

We followed the several guides and tutorials out there, basically ending up with regular `PresenterInterface` and `ViewInterface`, the latter being implemented by an `Activity` or a `Fragment`.

As for the `PresenterInterface`, we created an implementation of it and injected it in the `Activity` with dagger.

So the `PresenterImplementation` would keep track of status and execute all the logic behind the `Activity`'s behaviour.

We could successfully publish some application based on this pattern and everything seems to work quite well.

Lately thought, I started questioning this way of implementing the MVP pattern as it seems to me there's an extra logic layer added in between without being mentioned:

1. Isn't `View` the actual View? - I mean, you have an `Activity` and you use `setContentView(...)` then with `findViewById(...)` you get an instance of the class `View` which represents the actual view parsed from xml or programmatically built.
2. So if `View` is the View, isn't the `Activity` the actual presenter? - I mean the `Activity` concept itself is there to represent some logic behind the View.
3. Presenter should keep status: well there's a number of ways to keep status inside and `Activity`. Like, for instance `SavedInstanceState`, `SharedPreferences` etc.
4. All the `View` listeners (e.g. `OnClickListener`) are the methods the View can invoke on its Presenter while a compound CustomView may be created exposing methods to set values of its Sub-Views with an interface.

With the "regular" MVP pattern we used so far, it seems to me that the `Activity` is there just to access its `View`'s sub-views and "port" the Presenter's commands down to them.

---

So in my idea, you would have something like this:

### Structure

```
- main
|
|- MainActivity (class)
|- MainPresenter (interface)
|- MainView (interface)
|- MainViewImpl (class)
```

### MainView

```
public interface MainView {

  void setTitle(String title);
  void setBackgroundColor(int backgroundColor);

}
```

### MainPresenter

```
public interface MainPresenter {

  void awkwardButtonPressed();

  void bind(MainView mainView);

  void setup();

}
```

### MainViewImpl

```
public class MainViewImpl extends FrameLayout implements MainView{

  LayoutInflater inflater;
  TextView tvTitle;
  Button btnAwkward;
  MainPresenter mainPresenter;

  public MainViewImpl(Context context) {
    super(context);

    if(!(context instanceof MainPresenter))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("I need a MainPresenter");
    else mainPresenter = (MainPresenter) context;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    init();
    mainPresenter.bind(this);
    mainPresenter.setup();
  }

  public MainViewImpl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if(!(context instanceof MainPresenter))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("I need a MainPresenter");
    else mainPresenter = (MainPresenter) context;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    init();
    mainPresenter.bind(this);
    mainPresenter.setup();
  }

  public MainViewImpl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    if(!(context instanceof MainPresenter))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("I need a MainPresenter");
    else mainPresenter = (MainPresenter) context;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    init();
    mainPresenter.bind(this);
    mainPresenter.setup();
  }

  @Override
  public void setTitle(String title) {
    tvTitle.setText(title);
  }

  @Override
  public void setBackgroundColor(String backgroundColor) {
    super.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
  }

  private void init(){
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_view_layout, this, true);
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    btnAwkward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAwkward);
    btnAwkward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        mainPresenter.awkwardButtonPressed();
      }
    });
  }

}
```

### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainPresenter {

  private MainView mainView;
  private final Map<String, String> status = new HashMap<>();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("title")) {
        status.put("title", savedInstanceState.getString("title"));
      }
      if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("backgroundColor")) {
        status.put("backgroundColor", savedInstanceState.getString("backgroundColor"));
      }
    } else {
      status.put("title", "My Cool MVP");
      status.put("backgroundColor", "#00AAFF");
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("title", status.get("title"));
    outState.putString("backgroundColor", status.get("backgroundColor"));
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }

  @Override
  public void bind(MainView mainView) {
    this.mainView = mainView;
  }

  @Override
  public void setup() {
    this.mainView.setTitle(status.get("title"));
    this.mainView.setBackgroundColor(status.get("backgroundColor"));
  }

  @Override
  public void awkwardButtonPressed() {
    status.put("backgroundColor", "#00FFAA");
    status.put("title", "That Was Awkward...");
    mainView.setBackgroundColor(status.get("backgroundColor"));
    mainView.setTitle(status.get("title"));
  }
}
```

Finally the xml resources for the layouts here could be:

### main_activity_layout.xml

```
<com.sample.application.MainViewImpl
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cvMainView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

### main_view_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAwkward"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/awkward_button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This way the `MainViewImpl` is the View and the `Activity` is the presenter. Notice in both implementations the counterpart is always accessed through its interface, the `Activity` keeps the status in a map which puts in the `SavedInstanceState` when needed and retrieves back again when re-created.

---

## Questions

Does this make any sense? Is this really MVP? If not, what is the actual role of the `Activity` class in Android MVP? What could be the flaws of the presented implementation?

---

In case someone is wandering about how to unit test the Presenter's logic (which now is an `Activity`), here is how it can be done:

## MainActivityTest

```
public class MainActivityTest {

  MainPresenter mainPresenter;
  MainView mainView;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    mainPresenter = new MainActivity();
    mainView = Mockito.mock(MainView.class);
    mainPresenter.bind(mainView);
  }

  @Test
  public void testSetup() throws Exception {
    mainPresenter.setup();
    Mockito.verify(mainView).setTitle(Mockito.anyString());
    Mockito.verify(mainView).setBackgroundColor(Mockito.anyString());
  }

  @Test
  public void testAwkwardPressing() throws Exception {
    mainPresenter.awkwardButtonPressed();
    Mockito.verify(mainView).setTitle("That Was Awkward...");
    Mockito.verify(mainView).setBackgroundColor("#00FFAA");
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you just post the same code twice, with minor variations?  Please don't do that.  Choose one revision, and go with that.  You don't need to say "EDIT:" we [already know you edited](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/317504/revisions).

Comment: Hi, sorry, I think the major repost was in MainActivity because it changed quite a bit, while for the MainViewImpl I just posted the differential. So you think I should just replace the old code with the new one and in the EDIT note explain the changes and show the test class? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Yes.  Don't say "EDIT."  We already know that.  Also, for what it's worth, this post is really broad.  Do you think you could make your question more specific?  Focus it on the most pressing issue you are facing.  "Understanding Android MVP" isn't a question; it's the title of a programming course.